# Add a title to listView

Tags: android

Friends I am using a list view to add particular records. I need to add header for particular column in the list view. Please help me for the same. PLease find xml file code and screenshot with this post.[image]

XML FILE

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView1"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Title"
            android:textColor="#ffffffff"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/detail"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Detail"
            android:textColor="#ffffffff"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/country"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="India"
            android:textColor="#ffffffff"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@drawable/error"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can make custome row xml file as you require  and bind it with listview  [see](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/)